# Grafana - Show metric by field value

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I'm currently trying to create a graph on Grafana to monitor the status of my servers, however, I can't seem to find a way to use the value of a field as the value to be displayed on the graph. (Datasource is ElasticSearch)

The following "document" is going to be sent to GrayLog (which saves to Elastic) every 1 minute for an array of regions.

```
{
  "region_key": "some_key",
  "region_name": "Some Name",
  "region_count": 1610
}
```

By using the following settings, I can get Grafana to display the count of messages it received for each region, however, I want to display the number on the **region_count** field instead.

[image: Grafana Configuratio]
Result:

[image: Resulting graph]

How can I accomplish this? is this even possible using Elastic as the datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure that your document includes a timestamp in ElasticSearch.

2) In the Query box, provide the Lucene query which narrows down the documents to only those related to this metric

3) In the Metric line, press "Count" and change that to one which takes a specific field: for example, "Average"

4) Next to the "Average" box will appear "select field", which is a dropdown of the available fields. If you see unexpected fieldnames here, it's probably because your Lucene query isn't specific enough. (Kibana can be useful for getting this query right)

Comment: I can't really seem to get the appropriate query, it's showing fields for other documents but this one. Not sure if the lucene query can get more specific though, since I'm filtering by time range and the type of the log (name). I also seem to have lost my grafana panel now after restarting Elastic to expose it to Kibana.